# Execute slow sql simultaneously using python threads

Tags: python, sql-server, multithreading, concurrency

I have a very slow stored procedure (~30 min each run) that writes to an output table for each date it is passed.  It's only argument is that input date, and it needs to be run for each day in a range.  Using cursors or a for-loop results in no speedup since it is run sequentially and each run of the proc must wait on the prior one to  complete.

I have attempted to use threads to execute the proc for every date in a range, but I am not noticing the speedup I would expect.  Please let me know if I am either doing something wrong, or if there is a more generally accepted way to run concurrent SQL.  I would expect that since one execution takes 30 minutes, if I am running procedures concurrently then 100 dates should take a bit longer than the 30 minutes one date takes, but definitely not a linear increase.

Here are the relevant portions of the code:

```
def query(table_name,prod_dt):
    cur.execute("exec {} '{}';".format(table_name,prod_dt))
    conn.commit()

def next_workday(start_date,end_date):
    start_date=datetime.strptime(start_date,'%Y-%m-%d')
    end_date=datetime.strptime(end_date,'%Y-%m-%d')
    yield datetime.strftime(start_date,'%Y-%m-%d')
    while start_date<end_date:
        start_date+=BDay(1)
        yield datetime.strftime(start_date+BDay(0),'%Y-%m-%d')

def main():
    ''' 
    change func call in line 1 to last_workday_of_month or next_workday
    depending on what you need, monthly vs daily business days
    '''
    for date in next_workday('2014-12-31','2015-03-31'):
        t1=Thread(target=query,args=('slow_proc',date))
        t1.start()
        t1.join()
```

Comment: The bottleneck might very well be in SQL Server. Have you tried executing the SP parallel in multiple sessions (i.e. in multiple tabs in SQL Management Studio)?

Comment: One reason you might not be seeing a huge speed increase is because all of the threads are writing to the same table and SQL Server will have a lock preventing simultaneous table access.  I think the best solution is to change the Stored Procedure.

Comment: yes and i get the speedup i'd expect, which is basically 1:1 - for every tab it takes the expected 30 minutes.  It's hard to test with a large range though.

Comment: @ArinTaylor they all write to the same table, but all for different dates

Comment: Also, you are calling `join()` inside the loop, so your threads run in serial.

Comment: @kalhartt I'll admit i'm not very knowledgeable on threading in Python, but I'm not sure it makes a difference here as I have no other processes that would be blocked due to waiting on the join.  In any event I removed it and didn't notice much difference.